# If I drink a strength potion does it deal more damage against the ender dragon?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm wondering if I drink a strength potion, will it be easier to kill the ender dragon?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [strength potions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Potion#Potion_of_Strength) increase the damage you inflict to the dragon, but only for your sword attacks, not with the bow.

There is a [tutorial on the Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Defeating_the_ender_dragon) on how to defeat the dragon, and it includes a section about [useful potions](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Defeating_the_ender_dragon#Potions).

I defeated the dragon recently, and the only potions I took were strength II, and a couple of instant healths. But I already had an elytra and *a lot* of rockets, otherwise it would have been much harder.

Good luck!